# PHP Database connection class issues

Tags: php, mysql, class

So, I'm in the middle of writing a web application for one of my clients, and I've decided to keep the database connection in a class. The following code is what I have:

```
class databaseConnection {
    private $hostname = 'hn.app.dev';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'hn_app_dev';
    public function connect() {
        $host = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);
        if ($host) {
            $connection = mysqli_select_db($host, $this->database);
            if (!$connection) {
                die('An error occured while trying to connect to the database.');
            }
            return $connection;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the standard PHP function of `mysqli_query` to send queries to the database. I am using the following to send queries to the database:

```
function fetch_from_db($query) {
    $connection = new databaseConnection();
    $query = mysqli_query($connection->$connection, 'QUERY');
}
```

I'm new to using classes in my code. I'm still learning, as we all are. I've checked about but cannot find a fix for my issue. I know what the issue is: it's an issue with the class being an object, and something to do with fetching the returned `$connection` variable from it.

How can I fix this issue so that I can connect correctly to my database? Also, could anyone point me in the direction of some documentation that I could learn the fix so I can tackle this in future.

Thank you!

Comment: `$connection->connect()`

Comment: @Federico he's using `mysqli` functions, not `mysql`

Comment: my bad, I've read wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to keep it in a class, you never call the `connect()` function. But if you want it connected when you initiate the class, change the `connect()` function to `__construct()` and remove the `return` and assign it to a public variable.

```
class databaseConnection {
    private $hostname = 'hn.app.dev';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'hn_app_dev';
    public $connection;
    public function __construct() {
        $host = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);
        if ($host) {
            $connection = mysqli_select_db($host, $this->database);
            if (!$connection) {
                die('An error occured while trying to connect to the database.');
            }
            $this->connection = $host;
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you can get the database connection in your function like:

```
function fetch_from_db($query) {
    $connection = new databaseConnection();
    $query = mysqli_query($connection->connection, 'QUERY');
}
```

Now, after having said all that, you don't want to create a new instance in every function to access the database. So possibly making it static and create an `init()` function of sorts so it takes less memory in the overall application.

For class documentation PHP's [Classes/Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.classobj.php) page will help. Specifically the 'Examples' link.

Comment: I am getting a boolean response from this which is '1', rather than the connection itself. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, boolean because `mysql_select_db` returns true or false, but still works on the original connection. Updated code example.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different ways you could write a object to handle connections and queries to the database.

What matters most is what your trying to achieve.

I would think these would be a few features you would like to have.

- Single Connection
- Runs SQL and returns mysqli results.
- Access to the connection for escaping values.
- It looks like you want to store your credentials within the object it self. ( I would suggest passing these in as a value in `__construct()`

These are a few basic features, that could easily be expanded apon.

```
 class databaseConnection {
    //private $hostname = 'hn.app.dev';
    //private $username = 'root';
    //private $password = '';
    //private $database = 'hn_app_dev';

    private $connection; // this is where the object will store the connection for other methods to access it
    
    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    //public function connect() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
        if ($host) {
            $this->connection->select_db($database); 
            if (!$this->connection) {
                die('An error occured while trying to connect to the database.');
            }
            return $connection;
        }
    }

    // this is so databaseConnection $db can access the connection for escaping MySQLi SQL
    public function connection(){
         return $this->connection;
    }

    function fetch_from_db($query) {
        //$connection = new databaseConnection(); // I don't believe you really want to create a instance of this object inside of itself
        //$query = mysqli_query($connection->$connection, 'QUERY');
        $query = $this->connection->query($query); // we will use the object oriented style instead of the above procedural line
        return $query; // return the results to the $results var in the bottom example
    }

    // this is a magic function that is called when the object is destroyed, so we will close the connection to avoid to many connections
    function __destruct(){
      $this->connection()->close();
    }
}


// make a new datbaseConnection class with specific credentials
$db = new databaseConnection('localhost', 'someuser', 'somepass', 'somedb');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 100';

// call the fetch_from_db function from the new databaseConnection $db
$results = $db->fetch_from_db($sql);

// print the results
while($result = $results->fetch_assoc()){
  print_r($result); // print_r on each row selected from db
}
```

You can learn more about OOP and PHP Objects in the Manual and there are many tutorials available online about specifically classes to manage database connections and queries.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very nice and thought out answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class databaseConnection {
    private $hostname = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'onlinylh_sggsfaculty';
    public function connect() {
        $host = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password,$this->database);
        if ($host) {
            return $host;
        }
        else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
function fetch_from_db($query) {
    $conn = new databaseConnection();
    $r = mysqli_query($conn->connect(), $query);
}
fetch_from_db()
?>
```

This Worked For me.